# ModelState Not Valid as Hidden field not binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I'm quite a beginner at MVC and got stuck. I have searched but can't find a solution!
I am Posting a Create from my View but the Controller is unable to validate the Model state on the Line
`If ModelState.IsValid Then`
I have tracked the issue using

```
ModelState.Values.SelectMany(Function(v) v.Errors).Select(Function(b) b.ErrorMessage)
```

and receive this

```
(0): "The ClientJobID field is required."
(1): "The EmployeeID field is required."
```

Both of these should be coming from the View's "HiddenFor" lines but seem to pass null for some reason?
My Model is:

```
    Imports System
    Imports System.Collections.Generic
    
    Partial Public Class JobTimesheetT
        Public Property JobTimesheetID As Integer
        Public Property ClientJobID As Integer
        Public Property EmployeeID As Integer
        Public Property JobTaskID As Nullable(Of Integer)
        Public Property TaskDate As Date
        Public Property TotalHours As Nullable(Of Decimal)           
    
        Public Overridable Property ClientJobT As ClientJobT
        Public Overridable Property EmployeeT As EmployeeT
        Public Overridable Property JobTaskT As JobTaskT    
    End Class
```

The Controller snippet includes:

```
    <HttpPost()>
    <ValidateAntiForgeryToken()>
    Function Create(<Bind(Include:="JobTimesheetID,ClientJobID,EmployeeID,JobTaskID,TaskDate)>
                    ByVal jobTimesheetT As JobTimesheetT" ) As ActionResult

        '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        'SET RETURN VARIABLES
        '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        ViewBag.JobTimesheetID = jobTimesheetT.JobTimesheetID
        ViewBag.ClientJobID = jobTimesheetT.ClientJobID
        ViewBag.EmployeeID = jobTimesheetT.EmployeeID  
        ViewBag.JobTaskID = New SelectList(db.JobTaskTs, "JobTaskID", "JobTaskName", jobTimesheetT.JobTaskID)

        '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        'CHECK MODEL STATE
        '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        If ModelState.IsValid Then  '... Is not Valid!
```

And a snippet of the View is:

```
@ModelType xxx.JobTimesheetT
    @Code
        ViewData("Title") = "Add Time"  'Create
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.vbhtml"
    End Code

<h2>Add Time</h2>
<p> ClientJob id =  @ViewBag.ClientJobID</p>  'Added these to confirm values loaded correctly
<p>Emp = @ViewBag.EmployeeID</p>    

@Using (Html.BeginForm())
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) model.ClientJobID, ViewBag.ClientJobID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) model.EmployeeID, ViewBag.EmployeeID)
    @Html.Hidden("Client", ViewBag.Client)
    @<div class="form-horizontal" style="Text-align: center; margin: 10px,auto,10px,Auto;">
        <h4>Job Timesheet for: @ViewBag.Client</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(True, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})

        <h3>Task</h3>
        <div class="form-group" style="margin: 20px auto; width: 100%; display: inline-block">
            <div class="TimeSheetElementWide">                  
                @Html.DropDownList("JobTaskID", Nothing, "Select a Task", htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "TimeSheetDrop ", .style = "width: 300px", .required = "required"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.JobTaskID, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
            </div>
        </div>
... More fields here...
...
    
    <div class="form-group" style="display:inline-block; margin: auto; width:100%; text-align:center">
            <div>
                <input type="Submit" value="Save" Class="list-group-item btn btn-info" style="margin: auto;color: #2c76eb;font-weight: bolder;width:40%; height:40px" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
End Using
```

So why can't I get these values to bind and save to the Table? I would really appreciate any suggestions you may have please?

Comment: Try to pass ViewBag.ClientJobID and ViewBag.EmployeeID value from your controller 
 GET action method sample, E.g. I am posting.

`<HttpGet()>
Function Create()
{
 //your code
 ViewBag.ClientJobID='Some value';
 ViewBag.EmployeeID='Some value';

}`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The View loads correctly on the GET and does indeed display the two missing fields, if these are added to display in the View. They just don't seem to pass back to the BIND of the CREATE.

Comment: If you want to ignore the validation for those two fields, then you can write this line before your `ModelState.IsValid` statement.
`ModelState.Remove("ClientJobID");
ModelState.Remove("EmployeeID");`

Comment: @Shibu Thanks but as the error message indicates, these are required fields and their values need to be added to the database table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird, but it seems to have required me to better define the values for the hiddenFor's. Changing to:

```
    @Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) model.ClientJobID, New With {.Value = ViewBag.ClientJobID})  
    @Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) model.EmployeeID, New With {.Value = ViewBag.EmployeeID})
```

enabled the `ModelState.IsValid` to return `True`.

This now works, but i'm not sure why it didn't before? Perhaps someone can enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass ViewBag.ClientJobID and ViewBag.EmployeeID value from your controller
GET action method sample, E.g. I am posting.

```
<HttpGet()>
Function Create()
{
    //your code
    ViewBag.ClientJobID="Some value";
    ViewBag.EmployeeID="Some value";

}
```